# Change operator depending on the xml data

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, dictionary, operators

I want to build a dynamic operator changer in a if loop. I get the operator greater than and less than from an XML and I store it in a dictionary.

```
private static IDictionary<string, Rule> machine = new Dictionary<string, Rule>();
```

This dictionary stores a key along with a class of 3 values say (machineID(string), InnerText(int) and operator (greaterthan or lessthan ))

In another class I am trying to retrieve InnerText and comparing it with the Opeartor that is saved, byt I face a problem that even the operator changes for every xml file. SO i want to change the operator dynamically depending on the dictionary values in the below if condition.

```
if (actualrange > newrange)
   machineHealth = false;
else
   machineHealth = true;
```

XML :

```
<condition type="healthy" operator="greaterthan">100</condition>
<condition type="healthy" operator="lessthan">30</condition>
```

I want to change the operator(> or <) symbol in the if condition above depending on the value from the xml each time.
How this can be done.

Comment: Will no work.  '>' is a special character so you need to use U+003E.  See webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string input = "<condition type=\"healthy\" operator=\"greaterthan\">100</condition>";

            XElement condition = XElement.Parse(input);

            XAttribute _type = condition.Attribute("type");
            _type.Value = "unhealthy";

            XAttribute _operator = condition.Attribute("operator");
            _operator.Value = "lessthan";

            condition.Value = "200";​
```

Comment: @jdwend    I didnt get the code which you told to try. Is this goin to replace the operators (>) in the if condition depending upon the operator value from the xml?